Quotients of finitely generated Abelian-by-$\mathbb Z^2$ group
Suppose $G$ is a finitely generated Abelian-by-$\mathbb Z^2$ group, i.e. it admits a short exact sequence $1 \to A \to G \to H \to 1$ where $A$ is abelian and $H = \mathbb Z^2$. Suppose in addition that $A$ is infinitely generated.
Is it always the case that $G$ has a quotient $Q$ of the form $1 \to A' \to Q \to H'\to 1$ where $A'$ is infinitely generated abelian and  $H'$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$?
(This is a follow-up question to the one I asked here. Thanks to Moishe for the simple example.)
In this case, a wreath product of a finitely generated abelian group with $\mathbb Z^2$ will satisfy such condition (as we can just quotient out one of the wreath products by $\mathbb Z$ ), but I don't think it holds for general. Any idea to construct a counterexample will be really appreciated.

Just a small remark, but your emphasis on "finitely generated" seems rather unnecessary: a quotient of a finitely generated group is always finitely generated.

@sTertooy Thanks, I have updated the question
